# How to get nested object data present in mongodb in C# / ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, asp.net-core-webapi

Currently I have data in this format:

```
{
  "_id": "6602fc150d713b8f94494338",
  "type": "Brands",
  "screenContext": {
    "title": "",
    "handle": "tapas-products",
    "media": [],
    "styles": {},
    "additionalInfo": {},
    "translations": {}
  },
  "sections": {
    "name": "Category 3x3",
    "type": "categories",
    "sectionPosition": 1,
    "styles": {
      "containerStyle": {},
      "titleNViewAllSecStyle": {},
      "tileStyle": {
        "tileSec": {
          "width": "48%",
          "marginHorizontal": "1%"
        },
        "tileImageSec": {},
        "tileImage": {
          "width": 160,
          "height": 160
        },
        "titleStyle": {}
      }
    },
    "additionalInfo": {
      "numOfColumns": 2,
      "noOfTilesOnMainView": 4,
      "showLabel": true
    },
    "subSections": [
      {
        "title": "Offers",
        "handle": "frontpage",
        "image": "products/abc.jpg",
        "navigation": {
          "tab": "AgriStoreTab",
          "screen": "AgriStoreProductsList",
          "params": {
            "nextScreenParamName": "currentScreenPayloadName"
          }
        },
        "additionalInfo": {},
        "styles": {},
        "translations": {
          "te": {
            "title": "ఆఫర్"
          },
          "hi": {
            "title": "ऑफ़र"
          },
          "ta": {
            "title": "சலுகை"
          },
          "kn": {
            "title": "ಆಫರ್"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "translations": {
      "te": {},
      "hi": {},
      "ta": {},
      "kn": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Basically when I am running this method:

```
public async Task<dynamic> GetAppScreensData(string type, string handle)
{            
     try
     {
          var pipeline = new[]
          {
               new BsonDocument("$match",
                   new BsonDocument
                   {
                   { "type", type },
                   { "screenContext.handle", handle }
                }),
                new BsonDocument("$unwind", "$sections"),
                new BsonDocument("$sort",
                new BsonDocument("sections.sectionPosition", 1))
          };
            
          var query = pipeline.ToJson();
          var data = await _context.AppScreens.Aggregate<BsonDocument>(pipeline).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
          var list = data.ConvertAll(BsonTypeMapper.MapToDotNetValue);
          var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
          var screenResponseList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(json);

          if (screenResponseList.Count > 0)
          {  
              var appScreenResponse = screenResponseList.FirstOrDefault();
              return appScreenResponse;
          } 

          return new {}; 
     } 
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          throw new ex;
     }
}
```

The main problem is when I am running this method, I am getting the response properly while debugging, but in Postman, the response appears like this:

```
{
  "_id": [],
  "type": [],
  "screenContext": [
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ]
  ],
  "sections": [
    [
      []
    ]
  ],
  "isActive": [],
  "isDeleted": [],
  "createdOn": [],
  "updatedOn": []
}
```

```
{
  "_id": [],
  "type": [],
  "screenContext": [
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ]
  ],
  "sections": [
    [
      []
    ]
  ],
  "isActive": [],
  "isDeleted": [],
  "createdOn": [],
  "updatedOn": []
}{
  "_id": [],
  "type": [],
  "screenContext": [
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ]
  ],
  "sections": [
    [
      []
    ]
  ],
  "isActive": [],
  "isDeleted": [],
  "createdOn": [],
  "updatedOn": []
}{
  "_id": [],
  "type": [],
  "screenContext": [
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ]
  ],
  "sections": [
    [
      []
    ]
  ],
  "isActive": [],
  "isDeleted": [],
  "createdOn": [],
  "updatedOn": []
}
```

What can be the reason for this? How to resolve it?

I tried to keep return type as `IEnumerable`, `BsonDocument`, `dynamic` but nothing works.

The mongo data can have further nesting of objects so that Json will be dynamic and I cannot keep any fixed model for this.

Comment: Can you show the code for your controller action that calling the method attached and what is the return type?

Comment: public async Task<ActionResult> GetAppScreensData(string type, string handle)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await _homeService.GetAppScreensData(type, handle);
                if (result == null)
                {
                    return Ok(new { });
                }
                return Ok(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }